# Redirect instead of modal on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have login into my app in modal form

```
<div class="user-link login" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Log in</div>
```

But when user is on mobile, I want **redirect him to example.com/login** instead of showing him a modal. I don't want php or js detection because of speed, better would be solution based on resolution with css, wouldn't be?

I thought this would be a solution

```
<a href="{{ path('login') }}" title="Log in" class="onlyMobile">
   <div class="user-link login" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Log in</div>
</a>

<style>
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
        .onlyMobile {
            display: none;
        }
    }
</style>
```

but it isn't, because redirect is not so fast, so user can see a modal first and after that he is redirected.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: You could start off the modal as hidden and show it to the user not on mobile, you could do a smooth animation for the modal appearing or something so it would look better?

Answer (score 0):

How could I not see?

```
<a href="{{ path('login') }}" title="Log in" class="user-link login mobileOnly">Log in</a>
<a class="user-link login desktopOnly" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Log in</a>

<style>
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
        .mobileOnly {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
        .desktopOnly {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
</style>
```